# get a number from string and paste it to caller-numpad in android

Tags: android

I am trying to experiment the numpad.
I have a string which consists a number "115" and a button.When I click the button, the app closes and the android phone's caller num-pad appears with the number "115".
So I searched over the internet but wasn't able to get a good tutorial or hint on how to this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ACTION_DIAL` *intent* as follows.

```
String number = "115";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));

startActivity(intent);
```